# Where does the Event object come from in addEventListener, if it isn't passed in to the callback?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", function(event){
    document.querySelector("p").textContent = event.target.value;
});
```

If I remove the `event` parameter, the code still works as expected:

```
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", function(){
    document.querySelector("p").textContent = event.target.value;
});
```

But how? My best guess is that it is somehow available through lexical scope in `addEventListener`, but I'm not sure. Can anyone confirm?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8mwqtxv/)

Comment: Some browsers have `window.event`

Comment: IE a long time ago established the weird mechanism of using what amounts to a global symbol to reference the current event object. Most browsers do that now, though I think Firefox doesn't.

Comment: @Pointy is correct. If memory serves (and I can't be bothered to go and check), Chrome and IE have a `window.event` while FF does not. So, you shouldn't rely on this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. I checked the debugger and couldn't see a global event object though.

Comment: Although, there it is as `window.event`. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event):

> The read-only Window property event returns the Event which is currently being handled by the site's code. Outside the context of an event handler, the value is always undefined.
>
> You should avoid using this property in new code, and should instead use the Event passed into the event handler function. This property is not
> universally supported and even when supported introduces potential fragility to your code.

---

> My best guess is that it is somehow available through lexical scope in `addEventListener`, but I'm not sure.

It is a global: `window.event`. It just happens to exist only while an event is being processed.

**Compatibility**: The `event` property of `window` is supported in IE and Google Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: Thank you! The debugger didn't show an `event` under globals, which is what threw me.